# Flutter: Unable to load asset Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/rose.jpg")

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I cant Upload image as a background to a stack, i have added the image in assets folder and added it to pubspec.yaml and showing me that error :

```
Exception caught by image resource service.
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/images/rose.jpg
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:225:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:668:31)
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:651:14)
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:504:13)
...
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/rose.jpg")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#dea48(), name: "assets/images/rose.jpg", scale: 1.0)
```

**Code:**

```
  return new Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,

  body: new Stack(
    children: [
      new Image(
        image: new AssetImage("assets/images/rose.jpg"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ],
  ),

);
```

[My Asset folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdZeD.png)

Answer (score 10):

Run `flutter clean` and run again.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Image.asset("images/abc.jpg"),
```

instead of this :

```
Image.asset("assets/images/abc.jpg"),
```

PLUS :

Make sure it's written in pubspec.yaml as

```
assets:  
- assets/images/    //ONLY
```

And update pubspec if you added a recent Image with

```
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assets folder is in the right place which is in the root of your project folder.

The error is because you're using the image Provider AssetImage instead of Image.asset("assets/images/rose.jpg").

After making changes to your image asset, make sure you save it to automatically retrieve the new image dependency or run $ flutter pub get.

Also check that you've added the image path to the assets subsection in your pubspec.yaml like this:

```
flutter: 

 assets:
    - assets/images/rose.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the asset in your pubspec.yaml file?

```
assets:
    - assets/images/rose.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your pubspec.yaml file is correctly indented as below. Incorrect spacing/indentation may result in the image not being found.

```html
flutter: 
  assets:
    - assets/images/rose.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

on your terminal :

`flutter pub get`

to refresh pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Stop your emulator and Project and Type :*flutter clean* in terminal and run again

Answer (score 0):

After added new assets, it's preferable to stop the current debug session and run again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I did a hot reload, and it worked fine. You can also try closing the simulator and running the project again.

Of course, this is after you are sure that the path exists and that the path is properly set up in the pubspec.yaml file.

Good luck!